# NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/form/input[1]"}

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the error message:

> NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"html/body/form/input[1]"}

when I try running the code below. 
And the `xpath` is correct I already double checked

```
package Package;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Selenium1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox");
    WebElement ele =driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/input[1]"));
    boolean displayedstatus = ele.isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("The display status :"+displayedstatus);

    boolean enablestatus = ele.isEnabled();
    System.out.println("The enable status :"+enablestatus);

    boolean selectedstatus = ele.isSelected();
    System.out.println("The selected status :"+selectedstatus);

    ele.click();
    selectedstatus = ele.isSelected();
    System.out.println("The selected status :"+selectedstatus);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle one of two checkboxes, you need to switch to `iframe` first and then search for the element.

```
driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox");
driver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");
WebElement ele =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Bike']"));
```

If after that you want to handle elements outside `iframe`, you might need to switch back with

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try searching for the elements within the iframe you must have to **switch the focus to the iframe** that you are dealing with.

Try this before searching for the elements within the iframe:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iframeTitle")));
```

In this case, the iframe Title is : **iframeResult**

Below is the code:

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Selenium1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_checkbox");

    //switching focus to iframe
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iframeResult")));

    WebElement ele =driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/form/input[1]"));
    boolean displayedstatus = ele.isDisplayed();
    System.out.println("The display status :"+displayedstatus);

    boolean enablestatus = ele.isEnabled();
    System.out.println("The enable status :"+enablestatus);

    boolean selectedstatus = ele.isSelected();
    System.out.println("The selected status :"+selectedstatus);

    ele.click();
    selectedstatus = ele.isSelected();
    System.out.println("The selected status :"+selectedstatus);



    }

}
```